# This assembly instruction occupy how much ROB cell

Tags: assembly, arm, pipeline, cpu-architecture

We assume that in an out-of-order pipeline instructions are divided into u-ops. These u-ops are then sent to a reservation station and reorder buffer to execute. For this ARM assembly code, I need to know how many ROB cells and u-ops are taken during execution.

```
    000101a8 08 35 91 e5     ldr        r3,[r1,#0x508]=>MyVariable                       
    000101ac 03 00 52 e1     cmp        r2,r3
    000101b0 1e ff 2f a1     bxge       lr
    000101b4 00 f0 20 e3     nop
    000101b8 00 f0 20 e3     nop
    000101bc 00 f0 20 e3     nop
    000101c4 00 20 94 e5     ldr        r2,[r4,#0x0]=>Barrier
```

If we suppose that MyVariable did not exist in the cache and that the load takes too long, then we can assume that all of the above instructions will be reside in the ROB at same time.

1. how many ROB cells are used at the same time?
2. will the "isb" instruction (flush pipeline) also flush the ROB?

Comment: Are you sure ARM CPUs decode instructions into uops?  It's a RISC ISA so it generally doesn't need to do that except for microcoded `ldm` / `stm` (aka pop / push).  x86 CPUs decode to uops because it's a CISC ISA and ALU operations can have a memory source or even memory destination (load + ALU + store).  But ARM is a load/store machine.

Comment: actually i am not experienced in arm architecture, but you give me a good point. so in this manner, every instruction from above code will occupy only one cell in ROB buffer?

Comment: I think it's likely that every ARM instruction uses exactly 1 ROB entry, except for rare microcoded instructions.  I think I've read that some ARM CPUs may avoid keeping NOP instructions in the ROB at all, but I'm not 100% sure that was an out-of-order ARM.

Comment: Thanks. i am sure that arm cortex-a9 (has out-of-order pipeline) keeps nop in ROB buffer. because if we set variables in manner that if condition was wrong in above code and branch prediction speculativly run if body, number of NOP instruction affect that barrier cached in l1 or no. for example with 3 NOP barrier is cached in l1 but with 4 NOP barrier did not cached in l1.

Comment: Huh?  NOP always has to get fetched and decoded, regardless of whether the pipeline drops it before issuing it into the out-of-order back-end or not.  So if speculative execution touches a NOP, it will be hot in L1i cache.

Comment: i meant Barrier variable cached in L1-D, not nop instruction. and i meant that if we increase number of nop instructions in above code because of ROB capacity limitation we can expect that somewhere Barrier should not be cached(i saw that with 3 nop instruction). but also may be i am wrong and reason is that fetch&decode take time and reason is not ROB capacity limit.

Comment: Ah I see what you're saying now.  Like a Spectre gadget.  If you put some high-latency work ahead of the mispredict, that would give you more time in the shadow of the mispredict before it's detected.  (You might need to make the branch depend on the high-latency dependency chain if your ARM CPU does fast-recovery the way Intel does since Nehalem.)  Then you could tell if it's ROB capacity limits instead of just detecting the mispredict before fetch/decode get to the load.

Comment: I did not heard anything about "fast-recovery" and could not find useful information in internet. could you please briefly describe it or reference me to a doc?

Comment: See my answer on [What exactly happens when a skylake CPU mispredicts a branch?](//stackoverflow.com/q/50984007)

Comment: which arm architecture and then from that which core are you interested in?

Comment: On arm cortex-a9 witch has armv7-a architecture. Thank you